# Wheatstone bridge Capacitor,Dead Capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

[image: Wheatstone bridge Capacitor,Dead Capacitor]

I want to know that if in a Wheatstone Bridge ,that is made of capacitors only
we have this condition $c_1c_3=c_2c_4$.

The $c_5$ capacitor would be dead and it's voltage would be zero? Actually I am looking for a mathematical proof.

Comment: What do you mean by dead? But yes, the voltage across C5 is zero when there is a voltage between the left side and the right.

Comment: I want to know why?

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake. If C1 ≠ C4, then there will be potential across C5 for oscillating inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that $C_{5}$ is absent, that the voltage at the connection
point of $C_{2}$ and $C_{3}$ is zero and that of the connection point of $%
C_{1}$ and $C_{4}$ is $V(\omega )$. The impedance of a capacitor $C$ at the
angular frequency $\omega $ is

$$Z(C)=\frac{1}{i\omega C}.$$

Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
V(A) &=&\frac{Z(C_{2})}{Z(C_{1})+Z(C_{2})}V(\omega )=\frac{1}{\frac{Z(C_{1})%
}{Z(C_{2})}+1}V(\omega ), \\
V(B) &=&\frac{Z(C_{3})}{Z(C_{3})+Z(C_{4})}V(\omega )=\frac{1}{\frac{Z(C_{4})%
}{Z(C_{3})}+1}V(\omega ).
\end{eqnarray*}
If $V(A)=V(B)$ then attaching $C_{5}$ does not change the situation since
there is no voltage across it. But
$$
V(A)=V(B)\Rightarrow \frac{Z(C_{1})}{Z(C_{2})}=\frac{Z(C_{4})}{Z(C_{3})}%
\Rightarrow Z(C_{1})Z(C_{3})=Z(C_{2})Z(C_{4})\Rightarrow
C_{1}C_{3}=C_{2}C_{4}.$$