# Capacitor Wheatstone

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

[image] 
I have no clue as to how to proceed as I have not encountered such a question before.. A hint would be enough.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106318/

Comment: Its a different question altogether

Answer (score 3):

You asked for a hint only...

You want the voltage across the galvanometer to be zero. You know how the voltage divides in the series resistors (when the same current flows through each). Voltage across a capacitor related to the charge and the capacitance ($V=\frac {Q}{C}$). The charge will be the same on both capacitors if no current flows in the galvanometer.

Can you now figure out how series capacitors act as a voltage divider? And thus how to give the two voltage dividers the same ratio (so that the voltage across the galvanometer will be zero regardless of the applied voltage)?

Comment: So the answer should be 9?

Comment: If the capacitance is larger the voltage is smaller (for the same charge). If the resistance is larger the voltage is larger (For the same current).

Comment: I got it . the answer is 1